# Update column values - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Sample dataset:

```
    id  count
0   3   NaN
1   3   cat
2   3   human
3   3   bird
4   3   NaN
5   8   pegion
6   8   NaN
7   8   NaN
8   8   rat
9   8   NaN
10  8   human
11  8   monkey
```

Loop through each row. In `count` column, value of `NaN` and `human` is 0. All other strings value is 1. Then sum with previous row value until `id` contains same value. (continue recursively)

The output I want:

```
    id  count
0   3   0
1   3   1
2   3   1
3   3   2
4   3   2
5   8   1
6   8   1
7   8   1
8   8   2
9   8   2
10  8   2
11  8   3
```

Comment: _Then sum each row one by one until id contains same value._ - This is very unclear.

Comment: sum with previous row value until id contains same value.

Comment: Yes, *continue recursively* is also unclear. And why does row 5’s value drop back to 1?

Comment: Please provide some sample code. What have you tried.

Comment: In row 5, `id` value is 8. So, it starts counting from begin. @Cimbali

Comment: @pythonnoob should be 0 then, no?

Comment: No bcz there is no `Nan' or 'human'. So it will consider 1. @Cimbali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done in 3 simple steps:

- find which rows are non-`human` and non-`NaN`
- group by `id`
- compute the cumulative sum in each group

```
>>> (df['count'].ne('human') & df['count'].notna()).groupby(df['id']).cumsum()
0     0
1     1
2     1
3     2
4     2
5     1
6     1
7     1
8     2
9     2
10    2
11    3
```